# 'anime' doesn't exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i'm coding with create-react-app and typescript version 3.5.x.

i'm turning off the 'strictNullChecks' in tsconfig.

i want to use `props.location.state.anime`, but it gives me error 'anime doesn't exist on type '{}''

how to make it works?

here is my code snippet:

the link:

```
<Link to={{
        pathname: '/animes/' + collection.id,
        state: {
          anime: collection
        }
}}>
```

the page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

import { Column, List, Title, PageLoader } from 'rbx';

interface AnimeId {
  animeId: string;
}

type LocationState = {
  anime: any;
}

interface IEpisode {
  ...
}

interface ComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps<AnimeId> {}

class AnimeStreaming extends React.Component<ComponentProps, IEpisode, LocationState> {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    const animeEpisodes = this.state.items;
    let anime = {
      title: ''
    }

    if ((typeof this.props.location.state == 'undefined') || (Object.keys(this.props.location.state).length === 0)) {
      return (<Redirect to='/' />);
    } else {
      anime = this.props.location.state?.anime;
    }

    return (
     ...
  }
}

export default withRouter(AnimeStreaming);
```

Comment: did you try replacing ` anime = this.props.location.state?.anime;`  with  `anime = this.props.location.state.anime;` , if it throws error, check what you have in `this.props.location` ??

Comment: it gives error: Property 'anime' does not exist on type '{}' after typecheck result. i use typescript

Comment: please read my comment and follow the steps

Answer (score 0):

The props the component receives should be first, the state the component has second. However, this does mean that the state should be the state of the actual component. Since you're using this.state.items, I'm assuming that this is in your component's actual state. Also, did you perhaps mean to add LocationState to the RouteComponentProps?

```
interface ComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps<LocationState> {}

interface IAnimeStreamingState {
    items: any;
}

class AnimeStreaming extends React.Component<ComponentProps & IEpisode, IAnimeStreamingState> {}
```